# How to fix Google Calendar API error

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-calendar-api

I following https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/nodejs#step_3_set_up_the_sample

But it not worked and output below this:

```js
  var clientSecret = credentials.installed.client_secret;
                                          ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'client_secret' of undefined
    at authorize (/Users/prangyy/myApp/quickstart.js:32:43)
    at processClientSecrets (/Users/prangyy/myApp/quickstart.js:21:3)
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:404:3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try checking your client_secret.json in the [Node.js Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/nodejs#prerequisites).

It should contain clientID, auth_url, token_uri, auth_provider_x509_cert_url, client_secret, redirect_uris, javascript_origins.

```
{"web":{"client_id":"YOUR_CLIENT_ID","project_id":"google.com:my-project-1231","auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth","token_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token","auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs","client_secret":"YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET","redirect_uris":["YOUR_REDIRECT"],"javascript_origins":["YOUR_JAVA_ORIGIN"]}}
```

if not yet, follow this to get your `client_secret.json` file

> 1. Use this wizard to create or select a project in the Google Developers Console and automatically turn on the API. Click Continue, then Go to credentials.
> 2. At the top of the page, select the OAuth consent screen tab. Select an Email address, enter a Product name if not already set, and click the Save button.
> 3. Select the Credentials tab, click the Create credentials button and select OAuth client ID.
> 4. Select the application type Other, enter the name "Google Calendar API Quickstart", and click the Create button.
> 5. Click OK to dismiss the resulting dialog.
> 6. Click the file_download (Download JSON) button to the right of the client ID.
> 7. Move this file to your working directory and rename it client_secret.json.

I hope this helps. Goodluck :)

Comment: Thanks , It error because my client_secret.json invalid.

Answer (score 4):

Change lines 34-36 in quickstart.js to:

```
var clientSecret = credentials.web.client_secret; 
var clientId = credentials.web.client_id; 
var redirectUrl = credentials.web.redirect_uris[0];
```

(There's an error where they've used `credentials.installed` instead of `credentials.web`, which is what shows up in the client_secrets.json file.)

Answer (score 1):

No need to modify the original code if you check '**Other**' (as said in the tutorial) when you choose your **Application type** in the client ID creation page (step 4 of your pasted text)